# Is equivalent the memory used by an array of ints vs an array of structs having just one int?

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Considering the next struct...

```
struct Cell
{
    int Value;
}
```

and the next matrix definitions

```
var MatrixOfInts = new int[1000,1000];
var MatrixOfCells = new Cell[1000,1000];
```

which one of the matrices will use less memory space? or are they equivalent (byte per byte)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same size because structs are treated like any of the other value type and allocated in place in the heap.

```
long startMemorySize2 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
var MatrixOfCells = new Cell[1000, 1000];
long matrixOfCellSize = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

long startMemorySize = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
var MatrixOfInts = new int[1000, 1000];
long matrixOfIntSize = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

Console.WriteLine("Int Matrix Size:{0}.  Cell Matrix Size:{1}", 
    matrixOfIntSize - startMemorySize, matrixOfCellSize - startMemorySize2);
```

Here's some fun reading from Jeffery Richter on how arrays are allocated http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx

Comment: Nothing better than evidence, with its replicable extraction method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By using the [sizeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) operator in C# and executing the following code (under Mono 3.10.0) I get the following results:

```
    struct Cell
    {
        int Value;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            // result is: 4
            var intSize = sizeof(int);
            // result is: 4
            var structSize = sizeof(Cell);
        }
    }
```

So it looks like that an integer and a struct storing an integer consume the same amount of memory, I would therefore assume that arrays would also require an equal amount of memory.

Comment: Interesting, but the array would include some type information per cell?. Consider that a struct can implement an interface, so we can have... var Matrix = IMyStruct [100,100]; (where the Cell struct implements the IMyStruct interface) then, maybe, the CLR stores info about what implementator is assigned per cell.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting question, but I guess in the case that you store your structs as interfaces, boxing would occur which would increase the memory consumption since your structs would be converted to reference types then?
In case that you store your structs simply with their value type (as described in your question) no additional type information has to be stored.

Comment: Our knowledge is limited. I hope somebody well versed in these low level questions, like Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet, could answer it.

Comment: The array doesn't store type information per slot.  If you store structs in an array of interface type, the struct instances get boxed, and the boxed object contain the specific type.  The array doesn't have it, it just points to the boxed structs.

Answer (score 1):

In an array with value-type elements, all of the elements are required to be of the exact same type.  The object holding the array needs to store information about the type of elements contained therein, but that information is only stored once per array, rather than once per element.

Note that because arrays receive special handling in the .NET Framework (compared to other collection types) arrays of a structure type will allow elements of the structures contained therein to be acted upon "in-place".  As a consequence, if one can limit oneself to storing a structure within an array (rather than some other collection type) and can minimize unnecessary copying of struct instances, it is possible to operate efficiently with structures of almost any size.  If one needs to hold a collection of things, each of which will have associated with it four `Int64` values and four `Int32` values (a total of 48 bytes), using an array of eight-element exposed-field structures may be more efficient and semantically cleaner than representing each thing using four elements from an `Int64[]` and four elements from an `Int32[]`, or using an array of references to unshared mutable class objects.

Comment: The array doesn't even need to store the type of elements because that's included in its own type.  True for all kinds of arrays: value, reference, interface, etc.  Of course, with arrays of reference and interface types, the array just has handles to the actual items, and the items themselves store their own individual types.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I thought I read somewhere that the "type" field in the object header of an array merely identified it as an array and that the element type was stored as part of the array object itself.  In any case, an the array object would certainly store information sufficient to identify the type of the elements, whether it's accomplished by storing the element type separately from its, own, or by having a separate `Type` object declared for every combination of array dimensionality and element type and having each array store a reference to that.

Comment: Agreed.  I'm just saying that this isn't just for value type arrays, which are homogenous.  Arrays of polymorphic types still have just one common element type, and the varying type of elements is looked up from the object header of each element.